# how to fill the "data field" of wavfile

Tags: c++, c, wav

Hi i am trying to record from a board and i have successfully record 4 seconds. Problem is when i try to record for more time, i got an error telling me that there not enough memory. my target is to record a 5 minutes file. Until now i have create a buffer named snIn[256] where are the samples. i send it to a big buffer of [16K * 4sec] and when it is full, i create the wav file.

```
#include "SAI_InOut.hpp"
#include "F746_GUI.hpp"
#include "Delay.hpp"
#include "WaveformDisplay.hpp"
#include "SDFileSystem.h"
#include "wavfile.h"
using namespace Mikami;

#define RES_STR_SIZE 0x20
#define WAVFILE_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND 16000
#define REC_TIME 4

  //Create an SDFileSystem object
 SDFileSystem sd("sd");

bool flag = 1;
int count = 0;
char *res_buf; 
int rp = 0;
const int NUM_SAMPLES = WAVFILE_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND * REC_TIME;
Array<int16_t> my_buffer(NUM_SAMPLES);
int j = 0;
static const char *target_filename = "/sd/rectest.wav";     
const int SEG_SIZE = 256;
int sent_array = 0;


int rec(const char *filename, Array<int16_t> my_buffer)
{   
    j = 0;
    flag = 0;
    sent_array = 0;

    WavFileResult result;
    wavfile_info_t info;
    wavfile_data_t data;

    WAVFILE_INFO_AUDIO_FORMAT(&info)    = 1;
    WAVFILE_INFO_NUM_CHANNELS(&info)    = 1;
    WAVFILE_INFO_SAMPLE_RATE(&info)     = WAVFILE_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND;
    WAVFILE_INFO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE(&info) = 16;
    WAVFILE_INFO_BYTE_RATE(&info)       = WAVFILE_INFO_NUM_CHANNELS(&info) * WAVFILE_INFO_SAMPLE_RATE(&info) * (WAVFILE_INFO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE(&info) / 8);
    WAVFILE_INFO_BLOCK_ALIGN(&info)     = 2;


    WAVFILE *wf = wavfile_open(filename, WavFileModeWrite, &result);
    if (result != WavFileResultOK) {
        wavfile_result_string(result, res_buf, RES_STR_SIZE);
        printf("%s", res_buf);
        return result; 
    } else printf ("Open file success \r\n");

    rp = 0;
    WAVFILE_DATA_NUM_CHANNELS(&data) = 1;

         result = wavfile_write_info(wf, &info);
        if (result != WavFileResultOK) {
            wavfile_result_string(result, res_buf, RES_STR_SIZE);
            printf("%s", res_buf);
            return result; } else printf ("Write info success \r\n");

    while ( rp < NUM_SAMPLES ) {
        WAVFILE_DATA_CHANNEL_DATA(&data, 0) = my_buffer[rp];       
        result = wavfile_write_data(wf, &data);
        rp += 1;
    }

    if (result != WavFileResultOK) {
        wavfile_result_string(result, res_buf, RES_STR_SIZE);
        printf("%s", res_buf);
        return result; }  else printf ("Write Data file success \r\n");

    result = wavfile_close(wf);
    if (result != WavFileResultOK) {
        wavfile_result_string(result, res_buf , RES_STR_SIZE);
        printf("%s", res_buf);
        return result; }  else printf ("Close file success \r\n");

    //UnMount the filesystem
    sd.unmount();

    printf("Success rec !\r\n");
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    //Mount the filesystem
      sd.mount();

    const float MAX_DELAY = 0.5f;       // 最大遅延，単位：秒
    const int FS = I2S_AUDIOFREQ_16K;   // 標本化周波数: 16 kHz
    const uint32_t MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = (uint32_t)(MAX_DELAY*FS);
    SaiIO mySai(SaiIO::BOTH, 256, FS, INPUT_DEVICE_DIGITAL_MICROPHONE_2);
    Label myLabel(185, 10, "Delay System", Label::CENTER, Font16);
    // ButtonGroup: "ON", "OFF"
    const uint16_t BG_LEFT = 370;
    const uint16_t BG_WIDTH = 100;
    const uint16_t BG_HEIGHT = 45;
    ButtonGroup onOff(BG_LEFT, 40, BG_WIDTH/2, BG_HEIGHT,
                      2, (string[]){"ON", "OFF"}, 0, 0, 2, 1);
    const uint16_t SB_LEFT = BG_LEFT - 320;
    const uint16_t SB_WIDTH = 270;
    const uint16_t SB_Y0 = 240;
    char str[20];
    sprintf(str, "    %3.1f [s]", MAX_DELAY);
    SeekBar barDelay(SB_LEFT, SB_Y0, SB_WIDTH,
                     0, MAX_ARRAY_SIZE, 0, "0", "", str);
    NumericLabel<float> labelDelay(SB_LEFT+SB_WIDTH/2, SB_Y0-40, "DELEY: %4.2f", 0, Label::CENTER);
    DelaySystem delaySystem(MAX_ARRAY_SIZE);
    WaveformDisplay displayIn(*GuiBase::GetLcdPtr(), SB_LEFT+7, 70, 256, 9,LCD_COLOR_WHITE, LCD_COLOR_CYAN,GuiBase::ENUM_BACK);
    Label inLabel(SB_LEFT-30, 65, "IN");
    WaveformDisplay displayOut(*GuiBase::GetLcdPtr(), SB_LEFT+7, 130, 256, 9,LCD_COLOR_WHITE, LCD_COLOR_CYAN,GuiBase::ENUM_BACK);
    Label outLabel(SB_LEFT-30, 125, "OUT");

    int runStop = 1;
    Array<int16_t> snIn(mySai.GetLength());
    Array<int16_t> snOut(mySai.GetLength());

    mySai.RecordIn();
    mySai.PlayOut();
    mySai.PauseOut();


    while (true)
    {
        // On/OFF
        int num;
        if (onOff.GetTouchedNumber(num))
            if (runStop != num)
            {
                if (num == 0) mySai.ResumeOut();
                else          mySai.PauseOut();
                runStop = num;
            }

        if (mySai.IsCompleted())
        {
            for (int n=0; n<mySai.GetLength() ; n++)
            {
                int16_t xL, xR;
                mySai.Input(xL,xR);
                int16_t xn = xL + xR;
                snIn[n] = xn;
                my_buffer[j] = xn;
                j++;
                if (j == NUM_SAMPLES && flag == 1) {
                    rec (target_filename , my_buffer); } 

                int16_t yn = delaySystem.Execute(xn);
                mySai.Output(yn, yn);
                snOut[n] = yn;  
            }

            mySai.Reset();     
            displayIn.Execute(snIn);  

        }     
    }
}
```

I thought about a possible solution, to fill directly the "data field" of the wavefile with the snIn[256] buffer (instead of using my_buffer) again and again and at the end close the wavfile. Please let me know what you think about that and other solutions

Comment: the posted code does not compile and looks more like C++ than C.  Suggest, at the least, post the header files that are included, which board, which OS, etc

Comment: here are the library https://developer.mbed.org/users/shintamainjp/code/wavfile/#c853ba46d0b9 
i'm using stm32f746, mbed with keil ide

Comment: Hmm... maybe try writing smaller packets of data (since you can handle 4 seconds, maybe try two-second packets, so you can buffer one while the other writes)?  I'm pretty sure that works well with limited memory; I believe it's how, for example, _Tales of Phantasia_ managed to get the SNES to play a fully voiced opening song, by constantly loading tiny clips from the ROM into the sound processor's 32 kB RAM.  (It also had a custom sound driver, though, that managed to effectively double the sound RAM, but I digress...)

Answer (score 0):

things to note: 1) while a write operation is being performed, more data is still coming in.

At the very least I would double buffer that data, so can be writing one buffer while the other one fills.

Usually this means using an interrupt to collect the samples (into which ever buffer is currently being filed.)

the foreground program waits for the current buffer to be 'full', then initiates write operation.,

then waits again for a buffer to be 'full'

The interrupt function tracks which buffer is being filled and the current index into that buffer.  When a buffer is full, set a 'global' status to let the foreground program know which buffer is ready to be written.

The foreground program writes the buffer, then resets the status for that buffer.

Comment: i understand what you say but this is not my problem for now. i'm trying to record for a 5 minutes file but i have only 320k of ram on the board and i need to bypass this. how to make a long wav file without making a huge array ?

Comment: You've only got 320K of ram. So 4 seconds of audio at 44.1kHz is going to take more memory that you have. You need to double buffer and process in chunks of maybe 1024 samples, maybe go up if you're doing some priocessing. .